# Rally API "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed."

Tags: c#, rally

I am getting this error randomly when I attempt to upload an attachment.

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was
>   closed."

I have an import function using the C# RallyRestAPI which pulls data from Test Track and inserts it into Rally and copies in the attachments to Rally. My test data has 3 attachments which vary in size and are 350k, 63k and 43k. When I run my importer it will error on different uploads at different times. There is no consistency about it. Sometimes all three will fail, sometimes the 2nd one will and the third one will be successful. Creating and updating a story seem to be fine so it looks like a timeout but I am unsure how to change the timeout in the RallyRestAPI.

Has anyone else come across this issue using C# and the Rally RestAPI?

Here is my upload code. The call to Connect() returns a RallyRestAPI object and logs into that object. I re-login on every call to Rally (not sure if I need to do this or not).

```
private string AddAttachment(string reference, string name, string content, long contentSize, string type) {

            var restAPI = Connect();
            try {
                var attachmentContent = new DynamicJsonObject();
                attachmentContent["Content"]        = content;
                attachmentContent["Workspace"]      = _workspace["_ref"];
                attachmentContent["Project"]        = _target["_ref"];
                var result = restAPI.Create("AttachmentContent", attachmentContent);
                if (result.Success) {
                    _logger.Info("Attached the relevant AttachmentContent.");
                }
                else {
                    throw new LoggedException("Could not attach attachment to '" + reference + "' due to the following errors\n" + GetErrorList(result.Errors));
                }

                var attachmentContentRef = result.Reference;

                // DynamicJSONObject for Attachment Container
                var myAttachment = new DynamicJsonObject();
                myAttachment["Workspace"]   = _workspace["_ref"];
                myAttachment["Project"]     = _target["_ref"];
                myAttachment["Artifact"]    = reference;
                myAttachment["Content"]     = attachmentContentRef;
                myAttachment["Name"]        = Path.GetFileName(name);

                var contentType = "image/jpg";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type)) {
                    switch (type.Trim().ToLower()) {
                        case "doc":
                            contentType = "document/text";
                            break;
                        default:
                            contentType = type;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                myAttachment["ContentType"] = contentType;
                myAttachment["Size"]        = contentSize;

                result = restAPI.Create("Attachment", myAttachment);
                if (result.Success) {
                    _logger.Info("Attached the relevant attachment.");
                }
                else {
                    throw new LoggedException("Could not attach attachment to '" + reference + "' due to the following errors\n" + GetErrorList(result.Errors));
                }
                return attachmentContentRef;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new LoggedException("Unhandled exception occurred: ",ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Couple of questions - are you using a proxy? And what version of Rally Webservices does your code use?

Comment: No I am not using a Proxy and I have not specified in my connection a specific API version, letting it utilize the current version, which I believe is 1.37. 

The "content" parameter which is the data being uploaded is a Base64String using 'Convert.ToBase64String(fs)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing I've been able to upload attachments up to the Rally limit of 5 MB in size consistently without errors. Doesn't seem to relate to file type.

I'd recommend filing a Case with Rally Support (rallysupport@rallydev.com). Support has tools that can be used to identify bottlenecks - and try to see if they're server-side / data-related issues or client-connection issues.